# SVN won't let me rename or create a folder with a deleted folder's name

Tags: svn, rename, codeplex

Codeplex's SVN is not allowing me to create/rename folders to the name `A`.

I initially wanted to swap names of two folders (`A` and `B`). At the beginning, I renamed `A` to `C` then renamed `B` to `A`. When I tried to commit, some commits went through, others gave errors. So I deleted everything, updated and tried again. But now I can't seem to rename a folder to `A` or create a new folder named `A`.

When I try to create a new folder I get

Server sent unexpteced return value (200 OK) in response to MKCOL request for 
`/svn/!svn/REPO_UUID/myproject/trunk/partentFolder/A`

For renames, I get a similar error except instead of `MKCOL` it's a `DELETE` request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delete (ie rename in this case) folder `A` and add a different folder `A` in the same commit. You should:

1. rename A -> C
2. commit
3. rename B -> A
4. commit
5. rename C -> B